# Why adding abiFilters makes the app work correctly?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have been using in a project a native library for a long time and everything worked fine. Now I am using Android Studio `3.2.1` and Graddle `4.6`

As I said, everyhing went fine for a long time. Now I did some changes and rebuilt a new apk and when ran, on `System.loadLibrary("mylibrary")` I got this error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[...]couldn't find "mylibrary.so"`

In my project structure, I have `jniLibs\armeabi\mylibrary.so`.

So, I started searching for what that `UnsatisfiedLinkError` and what could cause it out of nowhere.

The solution that got the apk running as it should, was adding in my gradle file:

```
ndk{
  abiFilters "armeabi"
}
```

I don't understand why it worked last month and now it's not? Something changed in graddle? Also, could anyone explain what exactly abiFilters does? In their docs it says `Specifies the Application Binary Interfaces (ABI) that Gradle should build outputs for and package with your APK.` but I see it existed for a long time and it's not something new.

Comment: `UnsatisfiedLinkError ` means you missed the requried .so for your ABI, you can use APK analyser to check if you have it in place or not, i mean after you upgrade gradle. Because Android Gradle Plugin does have some changes since version 3.0.0, and 3.2.0 which may impact on the path of built native libs

Comment: But if it's a `armeabi` is should work fine for most devices, except tegra and x86 ones... As I said, adding `abiFilters` makes it work but I am not sure that is the right solution

Comment: Didn't the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` list the paths from where it attempted to load the library? That should give you some clue about what the problem is. You could also try looking inside the APK that you get without `abiFilters` - perhaps Gradle decided to add empty folders for `arm64-v8a` and/or `armeabi-v7a`, and perhaps that tricks the linker into attempting to load libraries from those folders at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are **NOT** using **default** build tools versions, e.g. NDK r18, for your Android Studio 3.2.1. Because **armeabi** has been removed since NDK r17.

> In my project structure, I have jniLibs\armeabi\mylibrary.so.

Try to consider to migrate your native code to those new ABIs. See: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

---

Below `abiFilter` will force your APK to package `armeabi` **only** and this ABI will become the primary ABI selection for all your devices.

```
ndk{
  abiFilters "armeabi"
}
```

In other words, no matter your device is `arm64-v8a` or `armeabi-v7a`, the APK manager will pick up the native libs from `<your-apk-path>/lib/armeabi/...`. So, from Android Studio, try "**Build**" -> "**Analyse APK**" to confirm this guess by examining your APK directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your so file missed prefix 'lib' ,`jniLibs\armeabi\mylibrary.so should be`

```
jniLibs\armeabi\libmylibrary.so
```

Comment: my actual library name has lib in front. I just added quick sample code and was not thinking that the name of the lib matters.

Comment: Open your apk file in AS ,check if your .so file is really packed into apk.